# Android Hilt inject an Application Singleton to a non Android class

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have a class that I want to be a Singleton in the App.

```
@Singleton
class SomeManager @Inject constructor() {
       .....
}
```

I want to inject it into a regular Kotlin class:

```
class UserManager @Inject constructor(
private val someManager: SomeManager,
private val isValid: Boolean = false){
    ....
}
```

But when I create the UserManager I do: `UserManager(true)` I get:

```
The boolean literal does not conform to the expected type UserManager
```

What am I missing? How can it be done?